# Postgres SQL query pivot without crosstab

Tags: postgresql

```
Select case_file_profile.case_file_id,
individual_profile.individual_name,
document_answer_details.document_template_question_id,
document.document_template_stage_id,
document.document_date, 
individual_profile.individual_date_of_birth, 
document.document_id, 
document.document_template_id,
case_file_individuals.case_file_individual_relationship, 
individual.individual_id, 
case_file_date_3, case_file_close_date,
individual_profile.site_id,
document_answer_number.answer_number

  FROM document


left join document_body on 
   (document.document_id = document_body.document_id)
left join document_answer_details on 
   (document_body.document_body_id = document_answer_details.document_body_id)
left join individual on 
   (document_body.entity_id = individual.entity_id)
left join individual_profile on 
   (individual.individual_id = individual_profile.individual_id)
left join case_file_individuals on 
   (individual_profile.individual_id = case_file_individuals.individual_id)
left join case_file_profile on
   (case_file_individuals.case_file_id = case_file_profile.case_file_id)
full join document_answer_number on 
   (document_answer_details.document_answer_details_id = 
   document_answer_number.document_answer_details_id)

 Where (conditions)
     )
     )
```

What it looks like

| client id | Question ID | Answer num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 53558 | expected 100271 | 7 |
| --------------------- | ------------------ | ------------ |
| 53558 | completed 100272 | 6 |
| --------------------- | ------------------ | ------------ |

What I'd like it to look like

| client id | expected visits | completed visits | % of visits completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53558 | 7 | 6 | 85% |
| --------------- | ---------------- | -------------------- | ------------------------ |

The results are two rows of data per person. I need the results in separate columns with an additional column with a calculated value from the two numbers I need side by side. The numbers are connected to the particular person via case_file_id from the table case_file_individual. I'm not able to use crosstab because I don't have write permissions. I've also seen and tried CASE statements and haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: The *separate columns* that you want are missing from the SELECT statement that you posted. Edit your question and clarify, better with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Thanks @forpas they were omitted for brevity. But I can add them back in.